# Error in GDCquery function in TCGAbiolinks package

Tags: r

I am trying to load Cancer data from GDC data portal onto R using `TCGAbiolinks` package.

Tried using all the parameters in the `GDCquery()` function, but was not able to load the data onto R.

Tried the below script:

```
query <- GDCquery(project = "TCGA-BRCA", 
                  data.category = "Transcriptome Profiling", 
                  data.type = "Gene Expression Quantification", 
                  workflow.type = "STAR - counts", 
                  legacy = FALSE, 
                  access = "open", 
                  platform = "IlluminaHiSeq_RNASeq", 
                  file.type = "results", 
                  barcode = listSamples, 
                  data.format = "TXT", 
                  experimental.strategy = "RNA-Seq", 
                  sample.type = c("Primary Tumor",
                                  "Recurrent Tumor",
                                  "Solid Tissue Normal",
                                  "Metastatic",
                                  "Solid Tissue Normal"))
```